# How to port a smoke simulation folder over to the render farm?

Tags: rendering, physics, smoke-simulation

I hope you can help me out with a question: How do you correctly setup your smoke simulation of 10 frames .blend scene to send it to the render farm services?
Let´s say the farm has started to simulate render frames from frame 1 (of 10) and it stops at frame 8 and it´s stopped: How can the farm continue on render 9 and finish on 10 without breaking the continuity on the render?
Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Farm has to simulate the cache locally to continually render if it´s stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render farms will take your .blend file and simulate it on their own site first, to generate the Cache folder. After that, the farm activates the distribute to render-per-machine (buckets assigned) from this file using path relative cache folder. This is how you get sequentially correct simulations on a render farm. It will involve human setup on the render farm.

Useful for hair, fractures, liquid. 
Caching in Blender can take many hours or some seconds depending on the SIZE of your scene (yes, blender units to Meters..etc..) so make sure you are working with the right proportion and scale.